# as3 - How to access child's child?

Tags: actionscript-3

I dispatched an event for a bullet to spawn on the page. However the bullet should be located in the area where the page's child child should be. There is a Page One `MovieClip`, which has a child named **player** and the player's child is **gun**. So I'm trying to keep the location and rotation of the bullet the same as the player's gun. So I need to access Page One's child's child. The player and the turret are using instance names and not variables.

I tried this code, but the bullet spawns in the page but will not spawn itself on the turret's location. This event is located in the PageOne class.

```
function fire(e:Event)
{
    var b:Bullet = new Bullet();
    b.rotation = player.turret.rotation;
    b.x = player.turret.x + player.turret.width * Math.cos(player.turret.rotation / 180 * Math.PI);
    b.y = player.turret.y + player.turret.width * Math.sin(player.turret.rotation / 180 * Math.PI);
    addChild(b);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand you well. But your problem is that the bullet is not spawned in the position of the turret's mouth?

Comment: Yes, because it seems like I can't access player.turret's location because it will not let me access a child's child somehow.

Comment: You can access to any instanced child inside the player `MovieClip`. Do you get any error? Remember that you need to translate the coords if you work with different scopes.

Comment: Then, you can access to that child. The wrong position is due to the coords conversion. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to the turret child. The problem is that you need to convert the coords inside the turret `MovieClip` to the coords inside the PageOne `MovieClip`:

```
var b: Bullet = new Bullet();

var turretpoint:Point = new Point(player.turret.width, 0);
var pagepoint: Point = this.globalToLocal(player.turret.localToGlobal(turretpoint));

b.rotation = (player.scaleX > 0) ? player.turret.rotation : 180 - player.turret.rotation;
b.x = pagepoint.x;
b.y = pagepoint.y;
addChild(b);
```

Comment: Sorry, I followed your steps and it still doesn't seem to do the trick. I'm not to sure on what the issue really is... The bullet seems to be spawning in the wrong direction and also not spawning on the turret's muzzle.

Comment: Post a little flash with the code to see the problem. If the turret is rotated you need to convert the coords inside it.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason, you need to convert the coords inside the turret. By other hand you need to change the angle guide by `scaleX` player property. See the edition.